# Flash Builder 4.5 installer not working

Tags: adobe, flash-builder

When I try to install adobe flash builder 4.5 on windows 7 it's giving the error:

> Installer failed to initialize. Please download adobe support adviser.

But the same installer was working fine with windows XP.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any other install is pending in your machine,
restart ur machine once and then install.It should work